# How to reset Function after value already added the fist time

Tags: python, python-3.8

So, The Game Works like this... If you have ever played Atlas this will be easy to understand

```
from easygui import *
import sys
import random
from contextlib import contextmanager
import colorsys

class States:
    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state

s1 = States("Alabama")
s2 = States("Alaska")
s3 = States("Arizona")
s4 = States("Arkansas")
s5 = States("California")
s6 = States("Colorado")
s7 = States("Connecticut")
s8 = States("Delaware")
s9 = States("Florida")
s10 = States("Georgia")
s11 = States("Hawaii")
s12 = States("Idaho")
s13 = States("Illinois")
s14 = States("Indiana")
s15 = States("Iowa")
s16 = States("Kansas")
s17 = States("Kentucky")
s18 = States("Louisiana")
s19 = States("Maine")
s20 = States("Maryland")
s21 = States("Massachusetts")
s22 = States("Michigan")
s23 = States("Minnesota")
s24 = States("Mississippi")
s25 = States("Missouri")
s26 = States("Montana")
s27 = States("Nebraska")
s28 = States("Nevada")
s29 = States("New Hampshire")
s30 = States("New Jersey")
s31 = States("New Mexico")
s32 = States("New York")
s33 = States("North Carolina")
s34 = States("North Dakota")
s35 = States("Ohio")
s36 = States("Oklahoma")
s37 = States("Oregon")
s38 = States("Pennsylvania")
s39 = States("Rhode Island")
s40 = States("South Carolina")
s41 = States("South Dakota")
s42 = States("Tennessee")
s43 = States("Texas")
s44 = States("Utah")
s45 = States("Vermont")
s46 = States("Virginia")
s47 = States("Washington")
s48 = States("West Virginia")
s49 = States("Wisconsin")
s50 = States("Wyoming")

print("Starting")
img = "/Users/Aayan/Downloads/Extra Random Projects/images.png"
start = buttonbox(image=img, title="Welcome", msg="Hi, Welcome to Atlas", choices=["Lets Go"])
name = enterbox(title="Enter Your Name", msg="Name:")
contin = buttonbox(msg="Hi " + name, choices=["Continue"])
main_men = buttonbox(msg="Which Mode Do You Want", choices=["USA-Beta", "International Mode-Not Available", "Exit"])
if main_men == "USA-Beta":
    botmult = buttonbox(msg="Which Mode Do You want to play", choices=["Bot-Not Available", "Multiplayer"])
    if botmult == "Multiplayer":
        print("Preparing 0bacse01219128")
        the = enterbox(msg="What is the 2nd Player Name", title="2nd Player Name")
        msgbox(msg="Hello " + the)
        print("Game Starting")
        list1 = ['a', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w']
        cc = str(random.choices(list1))
        firstletter = msgbox("The First Letter Is " + cc)
        cc = str(random.choices(list1))
        first1 = enterbox("Enter State")
        lol = first1.lower()
        xz = list(first1)
        so = list(cc)

        # Error Gate
        if xz[0] == first1[0]:
            print("\033[1;32;40m Bright Green  \n" + "TEST PASSED 0C1AE")
        else:
            print("\033[1;31;40m Bright Red   \n" + "TEST FAILED ER!ORR")
        if first1 == States:
            print("\033[1;32;40m Bright Green  \n" + "TEST PASSED 0D1AF")
        else:
            print("\033[1;31;40m Bright Red   \n" + "TEST FAILED ER!ORR")

        def stachek():
            if lol == ("alaska","alabama","arizona","arkansas"):
                msgbox("Correct")

                stachek()
            elif lol == ("california", "colorado", "connecticut" ):
                msgbox("Correct")

                stachek()
            elif lol == ("delaware"):
                msgbox("Correct")

                stachek()
            elif lol == ("florida"):
                msgbox("Correct")

                stachek()
            elif lol == ("georgia"):
                msgbox("Correct")

                stachek()
            elif lol == ("hawaii"):
                msgbox("Correct")

                stachek()
                
            elif lol == ("idaho","illinois","indiana","iowa"):
                msgbox("Correct")

                stachek()
            elif lol == ("kansas", "kentucky"):
                msgbox("Correct")

                stachek()
            elif lol == ("louisiana"):
                msgbox("Correct")

                stachek()
            elif lol == ("maine", "maryland", "massachusetts", "michigan", "minnesota", "mississippi", "missouri",
                         "montana"):
                msgbox("Correct")

                stachek()
            elif lol == ("nebraska", "nevada", "new hampshire", "new jersey", "new mexico", "new york",
                         "north carolina", "north dakota"):
                msgbox("Correct")

                stachek()
            elif lol == ("ohio", "oklahoma", "oregon"):
                msgbox("Correct")

                stachek()
            elif lol == ("pennsylvania"):
                msgbox("Correct")

                stachek()
            elif lol == ("rhode island"):
                msgbox("Correct")

                stachek()
            elif lol == ("south carolina", "south dakota"):
                msgbox("Correct")

                stachek()
            elif lol == ("tennessee", "texas"):
                msgbox("Correct")

                stachek()
            elif lol == ("utah"):
                msgbox("Correct")

                stachek()
            elif lol == ("vermont", "virginia"):
                msgbox("Correct")

                stachek()
            elif lol == ("washington", "west virginia", "wisconsin", "wyoming"):
                msgbox("Correct")

                stachek()

            else:
                msgbox(msg= "Incorrect, You Lose", title= "Incorrect")

                stachek()

        if first1 == States:

            stachek()
        else:
            stachek()
```

Here is the issue, I Need To run the `stachek` function Again But When I Do, It Does Not reset the First Time I initiated The code, Which means if I get Correct and press Ok to go to the Second try it shows Correct, what it is meant to do is say `Enter state:` and after that if correct then do `Enter state:` for as long as you get all correct, what it does it skips the question and keeps saying correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but I am certainly sure that the problem lies in indentation, meaning you code lies outside of `class`.

if you are trying to ask too many questions from a user after you specified who plays with whom, I believe this code may help you. I actually changed some part of the code, I hope you didn't mind.

```
from easygui import *
import sys
import random
from contextlib import contextmanager
import colorsys

class States:
    def __init__(self):
        self.States = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida","Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"]
        for i in range(0,len(self.States)):
            self.States[i] = self.States[i].lower()
        print("Starting")
        img = "/Users/Aayan/Downloads/Extra Random Projects/images.png"
        start = buttonbox(image=img, title="Welcome", msg="Hi, Welcome to Atlas", choices=["Lets Go"])
        name = enterbox(title="Enter Your Name", msg="Name:")
        contin = buttonbox(msg="Hi " + name, choices=["Continue"])
        main_men = buttonbox(msg="Which Mode Do You Want", choices=["USA-Beta", "International Mode-Not Available", "Exit"])
        self.list1 = ['a', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w']

        if main_men == "USA-Beta":
            botmult = buttonbox(msg="Which Mode Do You want to play", choices=["Bot-Not Available", "Multiplayer"])
            if botmult == "Multiplayer":
                print("Preparing 0bacse01219128")
                the = enterbox(msg="What is the 2nd Player Name", title="2nd Player Name")
                msgbox(msg="Hello " + the)
                print("Game Starting")        
                self.start_the_game()

    def start_the_game(self):
        i = 0 # for counting incorrect answers
        c = 0 # for counting correct answers
        t = 0 # for counting total number of questions asked
        while True:
            cc = str(random.choices(self.list1))
            msgbox("The First Letter Is " + cc)
            first1 = enterbox("Enter State")
            print(first1)
            if first1:
                lol = first1.lower()
                #xz = list(first1)
                print(lol)
                #so = list(cc)
                if lol in self.States:
                    msgbox("Correct")
                    c += 1
                else:
                    msgbox("incorrect")
                    i += 1
                t += 1
            else:
                break
        if t != 0:
            msgbox("correct percentage = " + str(c/t*100) + "%\nincorrect precentage = " + str(i/t*100))
        else:
            msgbox("you never played. exit game")
States()
```